# why one mapreduce job local bytes written value are much bigger than others?

Tags: debugging, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I write a mapreduce process,and i find one reduce job is slower than the others(all map jobs are finished).Then I find the "Local bytes writen" is:2,159,972,481, which is about ten times more than the others.What's the meaning and why?
How to solve this problem?
THanks.

Comment: The reason can be your data is skewed for a particular key, you should check your map output key and data for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mbaxi said it is probably that your file is skewed. The records from map output are distributed using a hash function over the key. So if your file is skewed you are going to have reduce nodes doing more jobs than others. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes,I found the output is skewed.But when I change the map file(there is just a print function in it...) to 'cat', the result is OK. 
So strange...